# in C#, save multiple files in selected path in saveFileDialog

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am using C# with sliverlight 5. I am using SaveFileDialog to get the userselected file name. Now I need to save multiple files at same location with different extensions. I tried the following

```
string directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dialog.SafeFileName);
Stream fileStream = dialog.OpenFile();

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
string sequenceFASTAFileNAme = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dialog.SafeFileName) + ".fa";
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, sequenceFASTAFileNAme);

if (!File.Exists(sequenceFASTAFileNAme))
{
    StreamWriter tw = File.AppendText(System.IO.Path.Combine(directory,sequenceFASTAFileNAme));
    tw.WriteLine("The next line!");
    tw.Flush();
    tw.Close();
}
```

But I am getting following error

> File operation not permitted. Access to path 'helo.fa' is denied.

at

> StreamWriter tw = File.AppendText(System.IO.Path.Combine(directory,sequenceFASTAFileNAme));

How can I just get the path of the selected file.

Comment: You'd have caught the exception earlier if you used the variables you created. You check if `sequenceFASTAFileNAme` exists yet try to create `Path.Combine(directory,sequenceFASTAFileNAme)`. Use `path` instead in both places, that's likely why you defined it

Comment: I see. That is a mistake from my end. But "directory" is coming out to be empty, so path is also just the filename.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] FileV = new string[3];
    FileV[0] = "val1";
    FileV[2] = "val2";
    FileV[3] = "val3";
    save(FileV);
}
private void save(string[] FileValue)
{
    System.IO.Stream myStream;
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter tw = System.IO.File.AppendText(saveFileDialog1.FileName + ".ex1");
            tw.WriteLine(FileValue[1]);
            tw.Flush();
            tw.Close();
            tw = System.IO.File.AppendText(saveFileDialog1.FileName + ".ex2");
            tw.WriteLine(FileValue[2]);
            tw.Flush();
            tw.Close();
            tw = System.IO.File.AppendText(saveFileDialog1.FileName + ".ex3");
            tw.WriteLine(FileValue[3]);
            tw.Flush();
            tw.Close();
            myStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "RestoreDirectory" doesnt show up for me. I am using Visual basic 2015.